# javascript: using data uri to show xml stream

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer

I've done the following to display my xml into a new browser window:

```
window.open('data:text/xml,' + encodeURIComponent( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02"><parent>test</parent></Document>' ));
```

works great in all browsers... but IE obviously. I'm using IE10. What should I do to get this to work ? Right now, the xml is URL encoded and does not show up in the new window.

Comment: For IE I think you will need to bounce it back to the server. There is  `window.open('javascript:document.write("' + "hello" + '")');` but I think you will have issues getting it to work with xml

Comment: docuemnt.write implies that I format the xml by myself. I want to let the browser do that. Sounds like a pain indeed....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [data Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28VS.85%29.aspx) article in the MSDN library:

> For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded
>   resources. Data URIs **cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements**.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded resources. Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements...

They can with this Javascript trick..

```
    var uri = 'data:text/xml,' + encodeURIComponent({your xml});

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = uri;


    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".xml";

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
```